# Single character instance from string

Tags: java, string, character

i was wondering how can i create a method where i can get the single instance from a string and give it a `numericValue` for example, if theres a `String a = "Hello what the hell"` there are 4 l characters and i want to give a substring from the `String a` which is Hello and give it numeric values. Right now in my program it gets all the character instances from string so the `substring` hello would get number values from the substring hell too because it also has the same characters.

my code :

```
public class Puzzle {


private static char[] letters =  {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i', 'j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s',
    't','u','v','w','x','y','z'};
private static String input;
private static String delimiters = "\\s+|\\+|//+|=";
public static void main(String[]args)
{
    input = "help + me = please";
    System.out.println(putValues(input));
}

//method to put numeric values for substring from input
@SuppressWarnings("static-access")
public static long putValues(String input)
{
    Integer count;
    long answer = 0;
    String first="";
    String second = "";
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(input);
    int wordCounter = Countwords();
    String[] words = countLetters();
    System.out.println(input);  

        if(input.isEmpty())
        {
            System.out.println("Sisestage mingi s6na");
        }
        if(wordCounter == -1 ||countLetters().length < 1){

            return -1;
        }
        for(Character s : input.toCharArray())
        {

         for(Character c : letters)
         {               
             if(s.equals(c))
             {
                count = c.getNumericValue(c) - 9;

                System.out.print(s.toUpperCase(s) +"="+ count + ", ");

             }              

         }
         if(words[0].contains(s.toString()))
         {

            count = s.getNumericValue(s);
            //System.out.println(count);
            first += count.toString();      


         }
         if(words[3].contains(s.toString())){

             count = s.getNumericValue(s);
             second += count.toString();
         }

        }
        try {

        answer = Long.parseLong(first)+ Long.parseLong(second);
        } catch(NumberFormatException ex)
        {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }

        System.out.println("\n" + first + " + " + second + " = " + answer);


    return answer;

}
public static int Countwords()
{
    String[] countWords = input.split(" ");
    int counter = countWords.length - 2;
    if(counter == 0) {
    System.out.println("Sisend puudu!");
    return -1;
    }
    if(counter > 1 && counter < 3) {
        System.out.println("3 sõna peab olema");
        return -1;
    }
    if(counter > 3) {
    System.out.println("3 sõna max!");
    return -1;
    }
    return counter;
}

//method which splits input String and returns it as an Array so i can put numeric values after in the
//putValue method
public static String[] countLetters()
{   

    int counter = 0;
    String[] words = input.split(delimiters);       
    for(int i = 0; i < words.length;i++) {

            counter = words[i].length();

         if(words[i].length() > 18) {
            System.out.println("One word can only be less than 18 chars");              
        }           
    }                                           
        return words;           
}
```

Program has to solve the word puzzles where you have to guess which digit corresponds to which letter to make a given equality valid. Each letter must correspond to a different decimal digit, and leading zeros are not allowed in the numbers.

For example, the puzzle SEND+MORE=MONEY has exactly one solution: S=9, E=5, N=6, D=7, M=1, O=0, R=8, Y=2, giving 9567+1085=10652.

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more in detail what the program would do? It sounds interesting and I would like to help, but I frankly didn't fully understand what the program shall do. More examples of input and expected output might be helpful.

Comment: What exactly is the question? Is it how to convert a String to an int once you know which character is which digit, or is it how to find out which character is which digit in order to provide the correct puzzle solution?

Answer (score 1):

import java.util.ArrayList;

```
public class main {

  private static String ChangeString;
  private static String[] ArrayA;
  private static String a;
  private static int wordnumber;
  private static String temp;
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    a = "hello what the hell";
    wordnumber = 0;
    identifyint(a,wordnumber);

}
public static void identifyint (String a, int WhichWord){

    ChangeString = a.split(" ")[WhichWord];

    ArrayA = a.split(" ");
    replaceword();
    ArrayA[wordnumber] = ChangeString;
    //System.out.print(ArrayA[wordnumber]);
    a = "";
    for(int i = 0; i<ArrayA.length;i++){
        if(i==wordnumber){
            a = a.concat(temp+ " ");
        }
        else{
            a = a.concat(ArrayA[i]+" ");
        }
    }
    System.out.print(a);
}
public static void replaceword(){
    temp = "";
    Character arr[] = new Character[ChangeString.length()];

    for(int i = 0; i<ChangeString.length();i++){
        arr[i] = ChangeString.charAt(i);
        Integer k = arr[i].getNumericValue(arr[i])-9;
        temp = temp.concat(""+k);
    }
    a = temp;
}


}
```

Change wordnumber to the word you want to replace each time. If this is not what you have asked for, please explain your question in more detail.